# How to see hash items in C++?

Tags: c++, hash

Hi so I have the following code and I want to be able to insert words into it and be able to see the stuff I put into the hash by printing it out. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <hash_map>
#include <set>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct nlist{
    struct nlist *next;
    char *name;
    char *defn;
};

#define HASHSIZE 101

static struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE];

unsigned hash(const char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;

    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

struct nlist *lookup(const char *s)
{
    struct nlist *np;

    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s,np -> name) == 0)
            return np;
    return NULL;
}

struct nlist *install(const char *name, const char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL){
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc (sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np -> name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else{
        free((void *) np->defn);

    }
    if ((np -> defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}

int main(){

    cout << "yo";
    string inline1;
    while (1){
        getline(cin, inline1);
        if (inline1 == "hash"){
            getline(cin, inline1);
            cout << hash(inline1.c_str()) << '\n';
        }
        else if (inline1 == "lookup"){
            getline(cin, inline1);
            cout << lookup(inline1.c_str()) << '\n';
        }
        else if (inline1 == "install"){
            getline(cin, inline1);
            string inline2;
            getline(cin, inline2);
            cout << install(inline1.c_str(), inline2.c_str()) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you bother to look at how your question is rendered after you posted it? Amd if not, why not?

Comment: Last time I took the time to give him a detailed answer he deleted the question =(

Comment: @Danny The question has been fixed already for you. But next time, you can select your text, then find the button at the top of the editing area, that says `101010`, and click it, to indent your code 4 spaces, which makes it show up as code instead of as regular text.

Comment: Or you could indent it all 4 spaces manually, but that's a lot more work. See also the instructions to the right of the editing area for more hints on how markdown syntax works, or the buttons above the editing area to automatically insert various types of markdown (bold, italic, links, lists).

Comment: Oh, and also remember to look at the preview below the text that you're editing, to see how it will be rendered. That will let you know if you have any problems with your formatting (assuming that you have JavaScript enabled on Stack Overflow; if you're using NoScript or something, be sure to allow JavaScript on this site to get all of the features).

Comment: Now, for your question, you're going to be more specific about what you're trying to do, and what problem you are having. What is currently not working? What are you trying to do? And is this a homework question?

Comment: No it is not a homework question. I am trying to figure out how hash map works so I can write a hash function for the words in a dictionary.

Comment: I am trying to add items to the hashmap and make it print items out. I think lookup is supposed to test if the items are in the hashmap and install is supposed to put items in the hashmap but right now they are not working.

Comment: @SuperString How are they not working? Try editing your question to say "I tried <doing this>, and I expected <this result> but instead it <does this>." Most people here aren't going to read through every line of code to figure out what problem you're having, nor try and run the code to see what you're seeing; but if you say what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened, it gives people a much better idea of what's going on, and lets them know where to look in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that you are printing out the pointer to the `nlist` item that you have looked up, rather than the value of the `defn` string within that item.

In your main loop, you have the following code:

```
else if (inline1 == "lookup"){
        getline(cin, inline1);
        cout << lookup(inline1.c_str()) << '\n';
}
```

What you probably want instead is:

```
else if (inline1 == "lookup"){
        getline(cin, inline1);
        cout << lookup(inline1.c_str())->defn << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading, or even using, the TR1 unordered_map or the GCC hash_map instead of building from scratch. Or get a copy of Knuth. Debugging this much of a hash table is more work than anyone here is likely to do.

You don't mention a platform, but if it is Windows they also have, depending on which version of visual studio, an STL-ish hash table for your to read and/or use.